# Sending mail using CDO JavaScript error - Server is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, smtp, hta, cdo.message

I got this code to send email using SMTP server, I tried many configuration of it that I found online, also VBscript similar code, and non of it is working.

I want to focus on this code, when I'm opening the HTA I'm getting error in line 8, says 'Server is undefined', What should I do to define it?

```
var cdoConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration"); 
cdoConfig.Fields("cdoSMTPServerName") = "194.90.9.22"; 

var cdoMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message"); 
cdoMessage.Configuration = cdoConfig; 

var cdoBodyPart = cdoMessage.BodyPart; 

cdoMessage.To = "aaa@gmail.com"; 
cdoMessage.From = "xxx@ddd.com"; 
cdoMessage.Subject = "CDO Test in JScript"; 
cdoMessage.TextBody = "This is a test email sent using JScript."; 
cdoMessage.send();
```

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: This is JavaScrit that run's in user's browser? If so, you can't do that. JS can't send emails directly by itself.

Comment: I saw many pages about it can be done with javascript.. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/a0e7a8ab-0311-4882-bd39-1638e34e4026

Answer (score 0):

Jan, you should see that code uses "Server" (VBS), is it recommended ¿?

You may check this:

1. Your server(running the code) is not allowed to send (mail forwarding).
2. Auth, .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoAnonymous, you should see if there's some auth on your mail server.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, I don't have local server, I want to use my ISP's SMTP, isn't it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, if is a shared SMTP then i believe the mail servers will ask you for a UserName and Password to authenticate and send the mail.

Comment: This is what I thought, but it isn't working.. What can I do?

Comment: Could you give more background of what you're using? (ASP?) and more detailed code and error message.

Comment: I wrote the complete code in the question. No server language involved.. Only JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delayed response looks like instead of using the server ip you need to spicify the server address for example smptout.secureserver.net but replace with your smpt address also most smtp server require username and password you will need to define these in your code.
in vbs it would be defined like so

```
Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
emailConfig.Fields("smtpserver") = "your smtp address"
emailConfig.Fields("smtpserverport") = your smpt port
emailConfig.Fields("sendusing")= 2  
emailConfig.Fields("smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("smtpusessl") = true/false "used for ssl" 
emailConfig.Fields("sendusername") = "your smtp username"
emailConfig.Fields("sendpassword") = "your smtp password"
emailConfig.Fields.Update
```

i do not know js very well so i am unable to convert the vbs code to work in js. i hope this is some help